# aggregate matrix rows based on groups given in a list

Tags: r, list, vectorization

I have the following matrix `M`

```
structure(c(0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 423, 176, 135, 
30, 4), .Dim = c(5L, 19L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("pregnant_min", 
"glucose_min", "blood_min", "skin_min", "INSULIN_min", "MASS_min", 
"DIAB_min", "AGE_min", "CLASS_min", "pregnant_max", "glucose_max", 
"blood_max", "skin_max", "INSULIN_max", "MASS_max", "DIAB_max", 
"AGE_max", "CLASS_max", "NumOfObser")))
```

and a list `L`:

```
L = list(1L, 2L, 3:5)
```

The elements of the list indicate which rows of `M` should be grouped together.
The first and second lines should be groups of their own. The 3-5 lines should form a group in the following sense:

Rows 3-5 of M should be replaced with one row, whose `min` of every value should be the `min` of the minimum of rows 3-5, the `max` should be the maximum, and its number of observations should be the sum.

So the output should look like this:

```
structure(c(0, 0.2, 0.4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.2, 0.4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 423, 
176, 169), .Dim = c(3L, 19L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("pregnant_min", 
"glucose_min", "blood_min", "skin_min", "INSULIN_min", "MASS_min", 
"DIAB_min", "AGE_min", "CLASS_min", "pregnant_max", "glucose_max", 
"blood_max", "skin_max", "INSULIN_max", "MASS_max", "DIAB_max", 
"AGE_max", "CLASS_max", "NumOfObser")))
```

The elements of the list `L` can be composed of any combination of 1-5, corresponding to the number of rows of `M`.

How can I achieve this output in the general case? So far I have looped through the elements of `L`, but I am pretty sure there is a more neat/efficient way of doing this.

Comment: You can construct the grouping variable so: `group <- rep(1:length(L), lengths(L))`

Comment: and how do I form all the maxima/minima of the different variables?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505701/grouping-functions-tapply-by-aggregate-and-the-apply-family

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
library(matrixStats)
#Get index of "min" cols
min_col <- grep("min", colnames(M))
#Get index of "max" cols
max_col <- grep("max", colnames(M))

setNames(do.call("rbind.data.frame", lapply(L, function(x) {
         if (length(x) > 1)
           c(colMins(M[x, min_col]), colMaxs(M[x, max_col]), sum(M[x, "NumOfObser"]))
         else
           M[x, ]
})), colnames(M))


#  pregnant_min glucose_min blood_min skin_min INSULIN_min MASS_min DIAB_min AGE_min
#1          0.0           0         0        0           0        0        0       0
#2          0.2           0         0        0           0        0        0       0
#3          0.4           0         0        0           0        0        0       0

#  CLASS_min pregnant_max glucose_max blood_max skin_max INSULIN_max MASS_max DIAB_max
#1         0          0.2           1         1        1           1        1        1
#2         0          0.4           1         1        1           1        1        1
#3         0          1.0           1         1        1           1        1        1

#  AGE_max CLASS_max NumOfObser
#1       1         1        423
#2       1         1        176
#3       1         1        169
```

We first find out the index of "max" and "min" cols and store them in separate vector. For every list element in `L` we check it's `length` and if it is 1 then we return the row as it is since `max` and `min` on 1 row matrix would give us the same row. If the `length` is greater than 1 then we take minimum of each `min_col` and maximum in each `max_col` take `sum` of "NumOfObser" column and return one row for that group. Finally we `rbind` all these rows and giving it's original meaningful names using `setNames`.

---

I have used `colMins` and `colMaxs` functions because it is easy to understand and makes the operation simple. If anybody is interested only in base R answer they can use `sapply` to get column-wise `max` and `min`

```
setNames(do.call("rbind.data.frame", lapply(L, function(x) {
    if (length(x) > 1)
      c(sapply(data.frame(M[x, min_col]), min), 
        sapply(data.frame(M[x, max_col]), max), 
        sum(M[x, "NumOfObser"]))
     else
       M[x, ]
 })), colnames(M))
```

Answer (score 1):

We assume that we should use `min` or `max` on a particular column if the column name ends in `_min` or `_max` and `sum` if the column name contains `Num`.

Now, create a grouping variable `g`.  We have used a general expression below but if we knew that `unlist(L)` equalled `1:nrow(M)`, as it does here, then `values` would equal `1:nrow(M)` and the expression for `g` reduces to the simpler expression `g <- stack(setNames(L, seq_along(L))$ind`.

Also define `fn` to be a character vector of function names (`"min"`, `"max"`, `"sum"`) to apply.  Then iterate simultaneously over the columns and `fn` using `mapply` and for each pair use `tapply` to process it as shown.

This should generalize as long as the same coding in the column names is used for `min`, `max` and `sum`.  The order of the input columns is arbitrary and will be maintained on output.  For example, if the column order were `pregnant_min`, `pregnant_max`, `glucose_min`, `glucose_max`, etc. it would still work and return the columns in that order.

No packages are used.

```
g <- with(stack(setNames(L, seq_along(L))), ind[order(values)])
fn <- sub(".*_", "", colnames(M))
fn[grepl("Num", colnames(M))] <- "sum"
mapply(function(col, fn) tapply(col, g, fn), as.list(as.data.frame(M)), fn)
```

giving:

```
  pregnant_min glucose_min blood_min skin_min INSULIN_min MASS_min DIAB_min
1          0.0           0         0        0           0        0        0
2          0.2           0         0        0           0        0        0
3          0.4           0         0        0           0        0        0
  AGE_min CLASS_min pregnant_max glucose_max blood_max skin_max INSULIN_max
1       0         0          0.2           1         1        1           1
2       0         0          0.4           1         1        1           1
3       0         0          1.0           1         1        1           1
  MASS_max DIAB_max AGE_max CLASS_max NumOfObser
1        1        1       1         1        423
2        1        1       1         1        176
3        1        1       1         1        169
```